# How to detect event of touching two buttons at the same time

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am programming an application with Flash AIR for Android.
I have two buttons, how can I trigger something when touch both buttons and hold for 3 seconds?
Any ideas? Thanks in adavance.

Comment: You wait until the buttons are touched, then start a timer, wait until 3000ms passed and then do your thing. downvoted because no code shown, no obvious attempt of solving the problem yourself etc.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some untested code that shows the pattern for what you're looking for.
Let's assume your buttons are called `btn1` and `btn2`:

```
//a timer to track 3 seconds of holding down both buttons
var touchTimer:Timer = new Timer(3000, 1);

//a dictionary to track when a button is touched and the corresponding touch id
var touchTracker:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

//add the touch listeners to the buttons
btn1.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, btnTouch, false, 0, true);
btn2.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, btnTouch, false, 0, true);

//listen for the timer's tick
///it will trigger whatever function should run after 3 seconds of holding down both buttons
touchTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, holdComplete, false, 0, true);    

//listen for touch end events, so you can reset the timer
stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, globalTouchEnd, false, 0, true);



private function btnTouch(e:TouchEvent):void {
    //associate the touchID with the object touched
    touchTracker[e.touchPointID] = e.currentTarget;

    //and vice-versa just for convenience
    touchTracker[e.currentTarget] = e.touchPointID;

    //if both buttons are being touched and the timer isn't running, start the timer
    if (touchTracker[btn1] && touchTracker[btn2] && !touchTimer.running) {
        touchTimer.start();
    }
}

//delete the records for the item that the touch ended on   
private function globalTouchEnd(e:TouchEvent):void {
    var obj:Object = touchTracker[e.touchPointID];

    //if there is a record for this touch id, delete it
    if (obj) {
        //null the reference the key points to
        touchTracker[e.touchPointID] = null;
        //delete the key
        delete touchTracker[e.touchPointID];

        touchTracker[obj] = null;
        delete touchTracker[obj];
    }

    //if either of the buttons are NOT being touched, reset the timer
    if (!touchTracker[btn1] || !touchTracker[btn2]) {
        touchTimer.reset();
    }
}

//this function runs if the timer is allowed to complete
function holdComplete(e:Event):void {
    trace("you held the buttons for 3 seconds, good for you");
}
```